# How to retrieve data from nested dictionary in java

Tags: java, dictionary

I have two dictionaries added into parent dictionary. How to retrieve data from a value (which is a dictionary)

```
import java.util.*;

class HelloWorld {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int count =2;
    
    Dictionary parent_dic = new Hashtable();
    Dictionary child1 = new Hashtable();
    Dictionary child2 = new Hashtable();
    Dictionary child = new Hashtable();
    
    child1.put("1", "one");
    child1.put("2", "two");
    System.out.println("Child1" + child1);
    
    child2.put("3", "three");
    child2.put("4", "four");
    System.out.println("Child2" + child2);
    
   for(int each_c = 1; each_c <= count; each_c++) {
       if(each_c==1) {
           child = child1;
       } else {
           child = child2;
       }
       parent_dic.put(each_c,child);
   }
   
    
    System.out.println("Parent" + parent_dic);
    System.out.println("test ::: " + parent_dic.get(1));
    
}
```

}

How to get value from resultant value (which is dictionary)?

Output:

```
Child1{2=two, 1=one}
Child2{4=four, 3=three}
Parent{2={4=four, 3=three}, 1={2=two, 1=one}}
test ::: {2=two, 1=one}
```

How to get value "two" from above test dictionary.

Comment: It isn't very clear what you are asking for. Could you elaborate on what you want the output to be/what isn't working? Side note : Avoid using raw types in Java

Comment: Not related to your problem, but you shouldn't use `Hashtable`: in most cases, using `HashMap` is preferred, and instead of `Dictionary`, you should use the interface `Map`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to rewrite your code in a way that made more sense to me.

I've added the use of proper types as well, using raw types in java is dangerous. The last line of my code does what I believe you want. Note the difference between using Integers as keys and Strings as keys.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dictionary<Integer, Dictionary> parent_dic = new Hashtable();
        Dictionary<String, String> child1 = new Hashtable();
        Dictionary<String, String> child2 = new Hashtable();

        child1.put("1", "one");
        child1.put("2", "two");
        System.out.println("Child1" + child1);

        child2.put("3", "three");
        child2.put("4", "four");
        System.out.println("Child2" + child2);

        parent_dic.put(1, child1);
        parent_dic.put(2, child2);

        System.out.println("Parent" + parent_dic);
        System.out.println("test : " + parent_dic.get(1));
        System.out.println("two : " + parent_dic.get(1).get("2"));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add generic types to your variable declarations (e.g. `Dictionary<Integer, Dictionary> parent_dic = new HashTable<Integer, Dictionary>();`)

Without them the compiler tries to add them in, not always successfully. The key and value pairs for your `parent_dic`, `child1`, and `child2` have defaulted to `Object`. You can add anything to them, even a `Random` object or an `ArrayList`. If you try to access the output of your last line by adding `.get("1")` it won't compile, because you are trying to use `get("1")` on an `Object`.

If you add the types, like `Dictionary<Integer, Dictionary>` you can access the data in the child dictionaries.